# Rendering issue for Facebook Crawlers - Ruby On Rails - Browser Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, browser

I'm developing a preview for facebook crawlers using `browser` gem .The problem is on rendering point . I don't know how to set the `respond_to` block in the controller . Currently , I've the following

```
def show_preview
@question = to_array(@question)
question_package = formatting_questoins(@question,params[:id].to_i)
@searched_question = question_package.first

  respond_with do |format|
    format.html { render 'show_preview' }
  end
end
```

It renders nothing . I tried with

```
  respond_with do |format|
    format.html { render 'show_preview' }
    format.json
  end
```

But it also renders nothing . Any help will be appreciating

Answer (score 1):

Rails knows which view to use for each controller action by convention. Your action `show_preview` of your controller `MyController` will use the view  `views/my_controller/show_preview.html.erb`.

You do not need to use `respond_with` nor `render` for that.

So your controller action becomes :

```
def show_preview
  @question = to_array(@question)
  question_package = formatting_questoins(@question,params[:id].to_i)
  @searched_question = question_package.first
end
```

And your view `views/my_controller/show_preview.html.erb` can now use `@question` and `@searched_question` in order to render something.

Documentation : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action